# Deploying inception V3 model (tensorflow code) in Kubernetes to run on gcloud

Tags: tensorflow, kubernetes, gcloud

I tried to do the set up procedure to run inception V3 model on gcloud using Kubernetes. I did all the steps in the following link and successfully did the job. (https://tensorflow.github.io/serving/serving_inception)

When I tried the last command to query the service at its external address from our local host with my own image address using the following command:

```
($ bazel-bin/tensorflow_serving/example/inception_client --server=104.155.184.157:9000 --image= MY_IMAGE_ADDRESS
)
```

I got the following error:

```
serving/bazel-bin/tensorflow_serving/example/inception_client --server=104.155.184.157:9000 --image=/path/to/my_cat_image.jpg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pouyanj/serving/bazel-bin/tensorflow_serving/example/inception_client.runfiles/tf_serving/tensorflow_serving/example/inception_client.py", line 24, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "/home/pouyanj/serving/bazel-bin/tensorflow_serving/example/inception_client.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/home/pouyanj/serving/bazel-bin/tensorflow_serving/example/inception_client.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
    import _pywrap_tensorflow
ImportError: No module named _pywrap_tensorflow
```

Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: Did you resolve this issue? I am working through the workflow in (https://tensorflow.github.io/serving/serving_inception) and getting stuck on the same last step as in this question. I'm getting a different error. Here is the link to [my stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43301262/how-to-troubleshoot-deployment-of-iinception-serving-running-in-kubernetes) describing the error I am getting. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!