# How to troubleshoot deployment of Inception serving running in kubernetes

Tags: tensorflow, kubernetes, grpc

I'm following the [Serving Inception Model with TensorFlow Serving and Kubernetes](https://tensorflow.github.io/serving/serving_inception.html) workflow and everything work well up to the point of the final serving of the inception model via k8s when I am trying to do inference from a local host.

I'm getting the pods running and the output of `$kubectl describe service` inception-service is consistent with what is suggested by the workflow in the [Serving Inception Model with TensorFlow Serving and Kubernetes](https://tensorflow.github.io/serving/serving_inception.html).

However, when running inference things don't work. Here is the trace:

```
$bazel-bin/tensorflow_serving/example/inception_client --server=104.155.175.138:9000 --image=cat.jpg

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/dimlyus/serving/bazel-
bin/tensorflow_serving/example/inception_client.runfi
les/tf_serving/tensorflow_serving/example/inception_client.py", line 56, in 
tf.app.run()

File "/home/dimlyus/serving/bazel-
bin/tensorflow_serving/example/inception_client.runfi
les/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 48, in run
_sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))

File "/home/dimlyus/serving/bazel-
bin/tensorflow_serving/example/inception_client.runfi
les/tf_serving/tensorflow_serving/example/inception_client.py", line 51, in 
main
result = stub.Predict(request, 60.0) # 10 secs timeout

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-
packages/grpc/beta/_client_adaptations.py", line 32
4, in call
self._request_serializer, self._response_deserializer)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-
packages/grpc/beta/_client_adaptations.py", line 21
0, in _blocking_unary_unary
raise _abortion_error(rpc_error_call)
grpc.framework.interfaces.face.face.AbortionError: 
AbortionError(code=StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE, details="Connect Failed")
```

I am running everything on Google Cloud. The setup is done from a GCE instance and the k8s is run inside of Google Container Engine. The setup of the k8s follows the instructions from the workflow linked above and uses the [inception_k8s.yaml](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/tree/master/tensorflow_serving/example/inception_k8s.yaml) file.

The service is set as follows:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    run: inception-service
  name: inception-service
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 9000
    targetPort: 9000
  selector:
    run: inception-service
  type: LoadBalancer
```

Any advice on how to troubleshoot this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

The error message seems to indicate that your client cannot connect to the server. Without some additional information it is hard to trouble shoot. If you post your deployment and service configuration as well as give some information about the environement (is it running on a cloud? which one? what are your security rules? load balancers?) we may be able to help better.

But here some things that you can check right away:

1. If you are running in some kind of cloud environment (Amazon, Google, Azure, etc.), they all have security rules where you need to explicitly open the ports on the nodes running your kubernetes cluster. So every port that your Tensorflow deployment/service is using should be opened on the Controller and Worker nodes.
2. Did you deploy only a `Deployment` for the app or also a `Service`? If you run a `Service` how does it expose? Did you forget to enable a `NodePort`?

**Update**: Your service type is load balancer. So there should be a separate load balancer be created in GCE. you need to get the IP of the load balancer and access the service through the load balancer's ip. Please see the section 'Finding Your IP' in this link https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/create-external-load-balancer/

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. I updated the question with more information. I do run both `Deployment` and `Service`. The service is setup via the yaml file. Please take a look at code snippet in the updated question.

Comment: Your service type is load balancer. So there should be a separate load balance be created in GCE. you need to get the IP of the load balancer and access the service through the load balancer's ip. Please see the section 'Finding Your IP' in this link https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/create-external-load-balancer/

Comment: The server IP I'm using above comes from `kubectl describe service inception-service` which specifies the LoadBalancer Ingress IP. Any other things I could check?

Comment: It may still be the security rules not allowing the ports on the Master/Worker Nodes. Can you check what NodePort is listed when you run kubectl describe service inception-service? It should be a port in the range of 30000-33000 and you'll need to allow that port in security rules for Master/Worker Nodes.

Comment: The `kubectl describe service inception-service` returns NodePort: <unset> 32760/TCP. This seems consistent with what the workflow from the  Serving Inception Model with TensorFlow Serving and Kubernetes suggests. How do I check that the NodePort is allowed in security rules for Master/Worker Nodes?

Comment: This answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21065922/how-to-open-a-specific-port-such-as-9090-in-google-compute-engine

Comment: Checked that the NodePort is indeed allowed.

Comment: Did you check the POD logs? `kubectl logs pod-name`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141301/discussion-between-drstarson-and-oswin-noetzelmann).

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out with the help of several tensorflow experts. Things started to work after I introduced the following changes:

First, I changed inception_k8s.yaml file in the following way:

*Source:*

```
args:
    - /serving/bazel-bin/tensorflow_serving/model_servers/tensorflow_model_server
      --port=9000 --model_name=inception --model_base_path=/serving/inception-export
```

*Modification:*

```
args:
    - serving/bazel-bin/tensorflow_serving/model_servers/tensorflow_model_server
      --port=9000 --model_name=inception --model_base_path=serving/inception-export
```

Second, I exposed the deployment:

```
kubectl expose deployments inception-deployment --type=“LoadBalancer”
```

and I used the IP generated from exposing the deployment, not the inception-service IP.

From this point I am able to run the inference from an external host where the client is installed using the command from the Serving Inception Model with TensorFlow Serving and Kubernetes.