# Tensorflow Kubernetes Integration Tutorial fails on Ubuntu Xenial

Tags: python, tensorflow, kubernetes

I am following the "Serving Inception Model with TensorFlow Serving and Kubernetes" tutorial from the tensorflow.org website. When I get to loading and exporting the model using

```
root@ecf82ac60c6b:/serving# bazel-bin/tensorflow_serving/example/inception_saved_model --checkpoint_dir=inception-v3 --output_dir=/tmp/inception-export
```

I get following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/serving/bazel-bin/tensorflow_serving/example/inception_saved_model.runfiles/tf_serving/tensorflow_serving/example/inception_saved_model.py", line 202, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/serving/bazel-bin/tensorflow_serving/example/inception_saved_model.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 124, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "/serving/bazel-bin/tensorflow_serving/example/inception_saved_model.runfiles/tf_serving/tensorflow_serving/example/inception_saved_model.py", line 198, in main
    export()
  File "/serving/bazel-bin/tensorflow_serving/example/inception_saved_model.runfiles/tf_serving/tensorflow_serving/example/inception_saved_model.py", line 91, in export
    table = tf.contrib.lookup.index_to_string_table_from_tensor(class_tensor)
  File "/serving/bazel-bin/tensorflow_serving/example/inception_saved_model.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/util/lazy_loader.py", line 53, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "/serving/bazel-bin/tensorflow_serving/example/inception_saved_model.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/util/lazy_loader.py", line 42, in _load
    module = importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/serving/bazel-bin/tensorflow_serving/example/inception_saved_model.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/__init__.py", line 82, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.eager.python import tfe as eager
  File "/serving/bazel-bin/tensorflow_serving/example/inception_saved_model.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/eager/python/tfe.py", line 76, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.eager.python.datasets import Iterator
  File "/serving/bazel-bin/tensorflow_serving/example/inception_saved_model.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/eager/python/datasets.py", line 23, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.data.python.ops import prefetching_ops
  File "/serving/bazel-bin/tensorflow_serving/example/inception_saved_model.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/data/python/ops/prefetching_ops.py", line 25, in <module>
    resource_loader.get_path_to_datafile("../../_prefetching_ops.so"))
  File "/serving/bazel-bin/tensorflow_serving/example/inception_saved_model.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/util/loader.py", line 55, in load_op_library
    ret = load_library.load_op_library(path)
  File "/serving/bazel-bin/tensorflow_serving/example/inception_saved_model.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/framework/load_library.py", line 56, in load_op_library
    lib_handle = py_tf.TF_LoadLibrary(library_filename, status)
  File "/serving/bazel-bin/tensorflow_serving/example/inception_saved_model.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 473, in __exit__
    c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: /serving/bazel-bin/tensorflow_serving/example/inception_saved_model.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/data/python/ops/../../_prefetching_ops.so: undefined symbol: _ZN6google8protobuf8internal9ArenaImpl10AddCleanupEPvPFvS3_E
```

I tried the solution on [How to troubleshoot deployment of Inception serving running in kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43301262/how-to-troubleshoot-deployment-of-inception-serving-running-in-kubernetes), but it does not apply to this problem. Has anyone encountered the same problem and maybe figured out how to solve it?